# Undefined control sequence \mcell@MB@ when using \diaghead

Tags: makecell

When I use the `\diaghead` provided by `makecell` package, I get `Undefined control sequence` errors. It seems the `\mcell@MB@` and `\mcell@MBjot` are both undefined.

Following is a simplified example adapted from Sec. 7 of [doc of `makecell`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/makecell/makecell.pdf).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}\hline
  \diaghead{\theadfont Diag ColumnmnHead II}%
      {Diag Column \\Head I}{Diag\\Column Head II} &
  \thead{Second\\column} & \thead{Third\\column}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\setcellgapes{8pt}` or some other dimension before `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be `\makegapedcells`. Without this the code works fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
%\makegapedcells
\renewcommand\theadset{\def\arraystretch{0.8}}%
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}\hline
  \diaghead{\theadfont Diag ColumnmnHead II}{Diag Column \\Head I}{Diag Column\\ Head II} &
  \thead{Second\\column} & \thead{Third\\column}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.